# Server principal "User" unable to access db "Metals" under the current security context

Tags: security, cursor, ssms, dynamic-sql, multiple-databases

I am attempting to create a query that accesses multiple databases on a single server.  I am using a cursor to access multiple other linked servers to the base server that the query is run on.  The issue that I am running into is the following:

```
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 43
The server principal "USER" is not able to access the database "Metals" under the current security context.
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 104
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 43
The server principal "User" is not able to access the database "Metals" under the current security context.
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Line 104
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.
```

The server shows that I am logged in, so why is the database using "USER" and "User" to attempt to access the "Metals" db?
I believe that the query to access the Metals db is correct because it returns the correct data when running it outside of the dynamic sql code.  I think the issue has to do with permissions, but I am unsure which permissions I should be changing for the user.  Currently, BLUser only has connect and select permissions.  Are there other permissions that I should be adding to allow them to access the Metals db?

The query is as follows:

```
DECLARE @location as varchar(50)
DECLARE @srv as varchar(20)
DECLARE @alphaDb as varchar(20)

DECLARE LabCursor Cursor FOR
SELECT Location, SQLServer, AlphaDB
FROM Labs

OPEN LabCursor

DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)

CREATE TABLE #tmpCombinedResults
  (
    Lab varchar(50) NULL, 
    Department varchar(50) NULL, 
    Instrument varchar(50) NULL, 
    Method varchar(50) NULL,
    Matrix varchar(50) NULL,
    StudyDate datetime NULL,
    StudyNumber int NULL
  )

FETCH NEXT FROM LabCursor INTO @location, @srv, @alphaDb

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

  -- query with both metals and alpha
  SET @sql = 
  ' 
    CREATE TABLE #tmpResults
    (
        Lab varchar(50) NULL, 
        Department varchar(50) NULL, 
        Instrument varchar(50) NULL, 
        Method varchar(50) NULL,
        Matrix varchar(50) NULL,
        StudyDate datetime NULL,
        StudyNumber int NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpResults(Department, Instrument, Method, Matrix, StudyDate, StudyNumber)
    SELECT t.Dept,
        oms.InstrumentID,
        oms.Method,
        oms.Matrix,
        MAX(oms.DateOfStudy) StudyDate,
        oms.StudyNum
    FROM [' + @alphaDb + '].[dbo].AnalRunSeq ars
        INNER JOIN [' + @alphaDb + '].[dbo].ottMDL1Studies oms ON ars.TestNo = oms.Method
        INNER JOIN [' + @alphaDb + '].[dbo].Tests t ON ars.TestCode = t.TestCode
        INNER JOIN [' + @alphaDb + '].[dbo].AnalRuns ar ON ars.RunID = ar.RunID 
            AND oms.InstrumentID = ar.InstrumentID
            AND oms.Analyst = ar.Analyst
        INNER JOIN [' + @alphaDb + '].[dbo].Instruments i ON oms.InstrumentID = i.InstrumentID
    WHERE oms.ActiveStudy <> 0
        AND oms.TypeOfStudy = ''MDL''
    GROUP BY oms.InstrumentID, 
        oms.Method, 
        oms.Matrix, 
        oms.StudyNum, 
        t.Dept, 
        i.InActive
    HAVING  t.Dept Not In 
        (''sub-org'',''sub'',''subpr'')
        AND i.InActive = 0
    ORDER BY oms.InstrumentID

    --error occurs in this part of the code
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) as Qty FROM ' + @srv + '.master.sys.databases where name = ''MetalData'') > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #tmpResults
        SET Department = ''ME'',
            Instrument = ms.InstrumentID,
            Method = ms.TestNo,
            Matrix =    ms.Matrix, 
            StudyDate = (SELECT MAX(ms.InUseDate)
                         FROM [Metals].[dbo].MDLStudies ms
                         WHERE ms.InUseDate = InUseDate)
        FROM #tmpResults tmp
            INNER JOIN ' + @srv + '.[Metals].[dbo].MDLStudies ms ON tmp.Instrument = ms.InstrumentID
        WHERE ms.Active = 1 
    END

    SELECT ''' + @location + ''' AS Lab,
        Department,
        Instrument,
        Method,
        Matrix,
        StudyDate,
        StudyNumber
    FROM #tmpResults
    ORDER BY Lab, Department, Instrument

    DROP TABLE #tmpResults
  '

  IF DB_NAME() <> @alphaDb 
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'EXEC(''' + REPLACE(@sql, '''', '''''') + ''') at ' + @srv 
  END

  INSERT INTO #tmpCombinedResults
  EXEC(@sql)

  FETCH NEXT FROM LabCursor INTO @location, @srv, @alphaDb
END

CLOSE LabCursor
DEALLOCATE LabCursor

SELECT * 
FROM #tmpCombinedResults

DROP TABLE #tmpCombinedResults
```

The current solutions that I have found on the web, all outlined [here](http://pmichaels.net/2014/02/19/the-server-principal-server-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-dbname-under-the-current-security-context/) didn't work for for me either.  This [one](https://support.managed.com/kb/a189/the-server-principal-is-not-able-to-access-database.aspx) in particular didn't make sense because I don't see Databases as an option in the left column of the Object Explorer Details.

Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by the user not having proper permissions in two of the five servers that were being referenced by the cursor.  Once the permissions were corrected, the issue was resolved.